# Capacitor - How to change app name on phone's language

Tags: javascript, android, capacitor

I've seen this in some apps , for example when the language is english , the app's name is in english but when the phone's language is changed to French for example ,it changes the application name to French .

By application name, I mean the name of app in the phone not when it opens.

How can I do this with capacitor ?
In the documentation, we only have one app name.
**capacitor.config.json -> appName**

My target: Android

Thanks